# It starts with O

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

What is the three word phrase I'm looking for here?

---

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Each group here is

> a depiction of how to draw a symbol:
>  [image: image from puzzle, with planetary symbol beside each group of text]
>
>
>  The symbols here, from the bottom up, are the astrological symbols for the **sun**, **Mercury**, **Venus**, **Earth**, **Mars**, **Jupiter**, **Saturn**, **Uranus**, and **Neptune**.
>
>  So the phrase you're looking for is likely something along the lines of **OUR SOLAR SYSTEM**!

Comment: This is ofc correct. Well done!

Comment: The 'our' part is very parochial... exclusionary speech to visitors from the other ones... :)